# Passing environment variables to application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, environment-variables, gradlew

In a spring boot application, I would like to pass some environment variables from env files (available for different environments) to the application.yml. We decided not to use spring profiles for different environments as using .env files make the later migrations to cloud easier for us. Defining these variables as following in the application.yml:

```
     datasource:
        driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        username: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}"
        password: "${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}"
```

Furthermore, I have exported all the environment variables in the .env file which also includes ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME} and ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD} using the following command:

```
    export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs -d '\n')
```

When running

```
    ./gradlew test
```

I get the following error:

```
    Missing property (SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME) for Groovy template expansion.
```

The problem is that gradle wrapper does not get the system environment variables or exported environment variables. Is there a way to solve this using .env files? Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Can you not use `@TestPropertySource`?

Comment: Adding a properties file did not help. Do I need to add any gradle configuration? Is it possible to do it without any code changes?

Comment: What is the format of .env files and how are those added to the Spring Environment?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've exported them as environment variables, you could remove `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` from your `application.yml`. Spring will search them automatically from the environment variables. You don't need to specify them like templates. An extreme usage is exporting all the properties via environment variables and leaving `application.yml` empty.

##### References

- Priority: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config
- Rules: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables